Non-linear crystals' interaction with light
This is really just a general question because we've been seeing non-linear crystals in a crystallography class, very briefly.
I was wondering how can we possibly understand the unique way non-linear crystals interact with light? Specifically, why does the polarization vector of the electric field become nonlinear, and why do we observe electric susceptibilities higher than the first order?

Do you mean non linear crystals?

Linearity is almost always an approximation, the first order approximation of a taylor series for a function. The relation between polarization and electric field is not really linear (what happens for electric fields stronger than the field between the electron and the nucleus?)
